# how to check single bit in byte using C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, boolean, boolean-logic

I want to check if single bit in received serial communication byte is high or low using C#

I was trying to write something like this:

```
if(BoxSerialPort.ReadByte() & 0x01)
```

or

```
if(Convert.ToByte(BoxSerialPort.ReadByte()) & 0x01)
```

The compiler sends this error:

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

How can I fix this?

Comment: `if((BoxSerialPort.ReadByte() & 0x01) != 0)`

Comment: The arithmetic AND operation you are performing here yields an integer, not a boolean value. Therefore you need to check whether that integer has the value you want or not. As was pointed out you check against `!= 0` or `== 0x01` (which should both work).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `&`-operator

```
if ((BoxSerialPort.ReadByte() & 0x01) != 0)
...
```

The `&`-[operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) checks every bit of two integer values and returns a new resulting value.

Lets say your `BoxSerialPort` is `43` which would be `0010 1011` in binary.

`0x01` or simply `1` is `0000 0001` in binary.

The `&` compares every bit and returns `1` if the corresponding bit is set in both operands or `0` if not.

`0010 1011`

&

`0000 0001`

=

`0000 0001` (which is `1` as normal integer)

Your if-statement now checks `if (1 != 0)` and this is obviously true. The `0x01`-bit is set in your variable.
The `&`-operator is generally good to figure out if a bit is set in a integer value or not.

Comment: it works! :) but shouldn't it work also without  the equality"!= 0"  ?
because the expression (BoxSerialPort.ReadByte() & 0x01) is basically boolean

Comment: Check my updated question.

Comment: C# does not automatically convert ints to bool and there exists no explicit casting between the two. C# != C

Comment: `(BoxSerialPort.ReadByte() & 0x01)` is not boolean, it is an integer. In your theory you would write `if (1) { ... }` which is (in C#) syntactically wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [compareTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.byte.compareto?view=net-6.0)

```csharp
    using System;

    //byte compare 
    byte num1high = 0x01;
    byte num2low = 0x00;


    if (num1high.CompareTo(num2low) !=0)
        Console.WriteLine("not low");
    if (num1high.CompareTo(num2low) == 0)
        Console.WriteLine("yes is low");

    Console.WriteLine(num1high.CompareTo(num2low));
    Console.WriteLine(num1high.CompareTo(num1high));
    Console.WriteLine(num2low.CompareTo(num1high));
```

output:

```
not low
1
0
-1
```